# Beginner needs help writing an SQL query of Expenditures by Month, county, and program

Tags: mysql, sql-server, select

I need help writing an SQL query that will yield the following report by program, county, and month.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKImH.jpg]

The table that has this information contains the following columns

[image]

I have come up with this query but it will only give me the totals for the month of January. Could some one show me how to get the rest of the months on the report?

```
Select ServiceCounty, Program, Sum(TotalPaymentTotal) AS January 
FROM Table1
WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '01/31/2014'
GROUP BY ServiceCounty, Program
ORDER BY ServiceCounty
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Example:

```
create table table1 (servicecounty varchar(20), program varchar(20), totalpaymenttotal int, entrydate date);
insert into table1 values 
('Mo', 'Program1', 100, '2014-01-01'),('Mo', 'Program1', 100, '2014-03-01'),
('Foo', 'Program1', 100, '2014-02-01'),('Foo', 'Program1', 100, '2014-04-01'),
('Mo', 'Program2', 100, '2014-01-01'),('Mo', 'Program2', 100, '2014-03-01'),
('Foo', 'Program2', 100, '2014-02-01'),('Foo', 'Program2', 100, '2014-04-01');
```

Query:

```
select 
   servicecounty,
   program,
   sum(case when month(entrydate) = 1 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as January,
   sum(case when month(entrydate) = 2 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as February,
   sum(case when month(entrydate) = 3 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as March,
   sum(case when month(entrydate) = 4 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as April,
   sum(case when month(entrydate) = 5 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as May,
   sum(case when month(entrydate) = 6 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as June,
   sum(case when month(entrydate) = 7 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as July,
   sum(case when month(entrydate) = 8 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as August,
   sum(case when month(entrydate) = 9 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as September,
   sum(case when month(entrydate) = 10 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as October,
   sum(case when month(entrydate) = 11 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as November,
   sum(case when month(entrydate) = 12 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as December
from table1
where year(entrydate) = 2014 -- gives you data for each month of this year
group by servicecounty, program
```

Result:

```
| servicecounty |  program | January | February | March | April | May | June | July | August | September | October | November | December |
|---------------|----------|---------|----------|-------|-------|-----|------|------|--------|-----------|---------|----------|----------|
|           Foo | Program1 |       0 |      100 |     0 |   100 |   0 |    0 |    0 |      0 |         0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |
|            Mo | Program1 |     100 |        0 |   100 |     0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |      0 |         0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |
|           Foo | Program2 |       0 |      100 |     0 |   100 |   0 |    0 |    0 |      0 |         0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |
|            Mo | Program2 |     100 |        0 |   100 |     0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |      0 |         0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0c80/1

Comment: Better to say `where entrydate between '20140101' and '20141231'` (assuming a date type of course).

Comment: I changed the EntryDate column's datatype to Date and then the query you wrote worked beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: @Marodr - to give closure to your question, please go ahead and accept any answer you feel appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add year and month of EntryDate into your group by aggregation.
There are builtin functions in sql server to extract the year & month of a Datetime field like this:

```
Select ServiceCounty, Program , YEAR(EntryDate) as Year,
       MONTH(EntryDate) as Month, Sum(TotalPaymentTotal) AS SumTotal  
FROM Table1  
GROUP BY YEAR(EntryDate), MONTH(EntryDate), ServiceCounty, Program  
ORDER BY ServiceCounty
```

If you need to group by an arbitrary part of a Datetime, you can use the DATEPART function.

This will get you long formatted data for each month/year. If you really need to get the months into columns, use Sql Server's PIVOT function.